# Cannot Group by Year

Tags: sql, t-sql

Beginner SQL Question:

I'm trying to do a group by, by year and I'm getting funny results. I am using SQL Server 2008.

First, I tried

`select  count(applicationkey) , approveddate from ida.applications group by approveddate`

To get a count of applications by date. However, I am interested in applications by year in stead of day so I tried

`select  count(applicationkey) , approveddate from ida.applications group by year(approveddate)`

When I do this, I get an error message -Column 'ida.applications.ApprovedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.-

However, if I do this I get results

`select  count(applicationkey)  from ida.applications group by year(approveddate)`

I get results. Its just I want to be able to see what year matches to which count, which I cannot do for some reason. Does anyone know why I am having this problem?

Comment: You must group by any non-aggregated columns in your query.  If you `group by year(approveddate)`, you need to select `year(approveddate)` and not `approvedate`

Comment: Ravi, a general question-asking tip: you can include things like platform (sql-server) and version (sql-server-2008) as tags in your question.  You stated them in your question, which already puts you ahead of a lot of question-askers, but the preferred method is to include them as tags.  You can do this by clicking the word 'edit' under your original question :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  select count(applicationkey), 
         year(approveddate) 
    from ida.applications 
group by year(approveddate)
```

`group by` must match fields in `select` if not using an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the correct parts there, just include the `year(approveddate)` in your select like so

```
select count(applicationkey), year(approveddate)
from ida.applications
group by year(approveddate)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a group query, columns selected have to be aggregate functions or appear in the group-by list, because otherwise SQL wouldn't know which of the multiple values for the column in the group to use.

You can fix your query easily by using

```
select  count(applicationkey) , year(approveddate)
from ida.applications group by year(approveddate)
```

-- the year displayed is from the group by list